# Replace a string in all included tex files in Texmaker

Tags: texmaker

I have created a tex file that includes several other documents (namely a main.tex that includes in bunch of chapterX.tex): is there any way to replace a word in all the included tex files with Texmaker? The basic replace function seems to scan only the current tex file.

I use Texmaker 4.1.1 (willing to upgrade is needed) with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: Hmm. On Linux, that's a one-liner, but maybe [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/674484/16658) helps you. It's a bat script that you could modify.

Comment: @Sebastian Thanks, yes on Windows I typically use Notepad++ to scan/replace strings across different files. I was curious to know whether this can be done within Texmaker.

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this is outdated ... but here it goes ... in TexMaker (Linux) there is no replace all ... best option is to copy text to gedit ... then use Search >> Replace >> type the string you want to replace >> replace all ... then copy back from gedit to TexMaker

I dont know why TexMaker doesnt have find all and replace all feature .. seems kinda odd for such a basic feature